# Debugging C program passing structs to multiple functions and recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, struct

I am tasked with debugging a C program that passes structs to multiple functions.  There were 16 errors to begin with and I am stumped on how to fix the final 3 (which I believe to be the same error).  I have been staring at the code for hours. What am I overlooking?

Using online IDE and codeblocks the error is:

error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
void print_complex(struct complex &a)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

MJG

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct complex
{
    int real;
    int img;
};


void scan_complex(struct complex &a) // function to read in complex number
{
    printf("Enter a and b where a + ib is the complex number."); //reading input
    
    printf("\na = ");
    scanf("%d", &a.real);
    
    printf("b = ");
    scanf("%d", &a.img);
}// end scan function


void print_complex(struct complex &a) //function to print complex number
{
    printf(" %d + %di", a.real, a.img);
}// end print funcion


struct complex * add_complex(struct complex *a,struct complex *b) //method to add two complex number
{
    struct complex *c = (struct complex *)malloc(sizeof(struct complex));
    
    c->real = a->real + b->real;
    c->img = a->img + b->img;

return c;
}// end add function


void multiply_complex(struct complex &a, struct complex &b) //method to multiply two complex numbers

{

    struct complex c;
    
    c.real = a.real*b.real - a.img*b.img;//multiplying
    c.img = a.img*b.real + a.real*b.img;

        if (c.img >= 0)
        {
            printf("Multiplication of the complex numbers = %d + %di", c.real, c.img);
        }
        
        else
        {
            printf("Multiplication of the complex numbers = %d %di", c.real, c.img);
        }
}// end multiply function

struct complex* f(int n, struct complex *c) //method to find addition of c , n times

{
    if(n==0)

        return c;

        return add_complex(c,f(n-1,c));
} // end f fuction



float abs_complex(struct complex c) //to find absolute

{
    return sqrt(c.real*c.real + c.img *c.img);
} // end absolute value function

int main()

{

struct complex a;
struct complex b;

scan_complex(a);

scan_complex(b);

printf("absolute of : ");

print_complex(a);

printf("%f\n",abs_complex(a));

printf("\n");

print_complex(a);

printf(" + ");

print_complex(b);

printf(" = ");

struct complex *c =add_complex(&a,&b);

print_complex(*c);

printf("\n");

multiply_complex(a,b);

printf("\n");

struct complex *d = f(3,&a);

print_complex(*d);

printf("\n");


return 0;

}// end main
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a reference in C; that's from C++. So you can't use symbol `&` in the type of the arguments of a function. In C, `&` means "address of". For instance when you write `scanf("%d", &x)` you're giving the address of `x` to `scanf`, so that `scanf` can store its result into `x`.

So you should instead declare the function as `void scan_complex(struct complex *a)`, and then in the body of the function, `a` is not a variable of type `struct complex`, but instead a variable of type `struct complex *`, which you can read as `pointer to struct complex`. Then in the body of the function, you can use it as `scanf("%d", &((*a).real);`, or the shortcut `scanf("%d", &(a->real));`

Comment: Thank you for the help.  As I make changes, I keep getting more errors.  I will start the debugging process over, starting with your revisions.